# How do I remove the word of the input from an output of objects?

Tags: javascript

I apologize for the poorly worded question.. I really didn't know how else to word this question, especially since I'm a newbie.

I'm trying to make a little game where you're given 4 random colors from a list of 6 colors, and to defuse the bomb you need to cut the wires following some rules like if you have a blue wire, you can't cut red or if you have a x wire you need to cut y, etc.

The first problem I've run into is I can't figure out how I'll get it so if the user inputs "Green" for example, "Green" will disappear from the 4 colors. So for example if you have Yellow, Blue, Green and Black, and the user chooses to cut "Green" then the next 3 colors will say "Yellow, Blue and Black"

Can anyone please help me out here?

```
var colors = ['Blue', 'Red', 'Yellow','White', 'Black', 'Green'];
var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
var color2 = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
var color3 = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
var color4 = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
console.log('The wires are: ' + color + ', ' + color2 + ', ' + color3 + ' and ' + color4);

const asdf = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

asdf.question('What will you cut?' , wire => {
    console.log(`You cut ${wire}!`);
    asdf.close();

    if (color == 'Blue' | color2 == 'Blue' | color3 == 'Blue' | color4 == 'Blue' && wire == 'Red') {
        console.log("Wrong wire!");
        return;
    }
    else {
        console.log("Nice!");
        }

    console.log('The remaining wires are: ' );
    asdf.question("Next wire?", wire => {
        console.log(`You cut ${wire}!`);
        asdf.close()
    })
})
```

Comment: you are using the bitwise `|` or - you want the logical or `||`

Comment: A more elegant way to write your condition would be `[color, color2, color3, color4].includes('Blue') && wire === 'Red'` instead of `color == 'Blue' | color2 == 'Blue' | color3 == 'Blue' | color4 == 'Blue' && wire == 'Red'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the string typed by the user is called `typedColor`, it would be:

```js
const colors = ['Blue', 'Red', 'Yellow','White', 'Black', 'Green']

const typedColor = 'Green'

const colorWithoutTypedColor = colors.filter(color => color !== typedColor)

console.log(colorWithoutTypedColor)
```

There is another way to do it if you want to keep everything in the variable color:

```js
const colors = ['Blue', 'Red', 'Yellow','White', 'Black', 'Green']

const typedColor = 'Green'

colors.splice(colors.findIndex(color => color === typedColor), 1)

console.log(colors)
```

EDIT: pick 4 randomly choosen colors from array of 6

```js
const colors = ['Blue', 'Red', 'Yellow', 'White', 'Black', 'Green']

function getXRandomColors(colors, x, result) {
  if (x === 0) return result // Exit contition (needed in a recursive function)
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)
  return getXRandomColors(colors, x - 1, [...result, colors[randomIndex]])
}

fourRandomColors = getXRandomColors(colors, 4, [])

console.log(fourRandomColors)
```

I hope you are familiar with recursive functions :), otherwise I can try to explain:

Recursive functions are functions that call themselves. To be sure that you do not make a infinite loop (and thus, a **stack overflow** ;)), you have to have an exit condition.
To understand what does this function, you can try to call it direcly with the exit condition: it returns an empty array. Then try so that in executes only one time (x = 1), you will see that first, I find an random index of the array. Then, it calls itself with the same `colors` array, with `x` which its value is one less, and finally `result` has one more value than before (you can see that the first time I call the function `result = []`).

Here, `x` acts like a counter that tell the recursive function when to stop.

Here is a good link to begin with: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-recursion-works-explained-with-flowcharts-and-a-video-de61f40cb7f9/

Comment: Hey, this is awesome, but the problem is I want only 4 randomly picked colors from the array, so what would be the best way to do that with your solution? I tried making another array for the new 4 colors but it just gives me undefined when I try to push the randomized colors into them. Thanks so much for your help though

Comment: Are you allowed to pick several times the same color in the random pick ?

Comment: Right now yeah, but that is something I wanna change once I figure this problem out

Comment: Ah this is amazing man, thank you so much, you've been so helpful. And no I don't understand recursive functions, if you can explain it'd be even more appreciated but otherwise I can try to figure it out!

Comment: I edited my answer again. Hint: if you manage to transform your array so that the color picked is removed just before calling the recursion, you will manage to have the exact bahaviour you want ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to store 4 colors in an array, NOT in variables.

```js
const colors = ['Blue', 'Red', 'Yellow','White', 'Black', 'Green'];
const wires = [
  colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)],
  colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)],
  colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)],
  colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)]
];

function removeWire(wire) {
  const index = wires.indexOf(wire);
  if (index > -1) {
    wires.splice(index, 1);
  }
}

// then

removeWire(wire);
```

Comment: Doesn't pop only remove the last element in the array? If I understood you right, that won't work, no? Because the color I want to remove could be anywhere in the array

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Edited the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your question, using a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) may make things easier.

You can populate your `Set` with 4 random colors using `add`, or during construction, then simply call `delete` whenever you wish to remove a color:

```js
// initialize set through constructor using array of strings
const colorSet = new Set(["Blue", "Green", "Red", "Black"]);
colorSet.delete("Blue"); // remove "Blue" from set
```

If you follow the link to MDN regarding `Set` you will find examples for common operations such as iteration and logging.